# Add custom subview to certain reusablecells in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a reusable cell in my UITableview, and I'd like to add a custom image only on certain cells.

Here is my code for example :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BCContactCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:contactCellIdentifier];
    ...
    if ([contact isFavorite]) {
        UIImageView * fav = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(280.0f, 2.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f)];
        [fav setImage:favoriteImg]; // already loaded
        [cell addSubview:fav];
    }
}
```

It works, and every favorite contact has the picture in its cell.
Except when I swipe down, other cell starts to take the picture as well, and I can't seem to figure it out.

Anyone can help me on how to do this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here we go,

give a tag number to your imageview, 
**fav.tag = 1290;**
later using that number we can get the old uiimageview back and remove it from the cell.
**else{
            [[cell viewWithTag:1290] removeFromSuperview];
        }**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BCContactCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:contactCellIdentifier];
    ...
    if ([contact isFavorite]) {
        UIImageView * fav = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(280.0f, 2.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f)];
        fav.tag = 1290;
        [fav setImage:favoriteImg]; // already loaded
        [cell addSubview:fav];
    }else{
        [[cell viewWithTag:1290] removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

*When it comes to UITableViewCells, they reuse already created cells. When they reuse old once. You have to remove the UIImageView you added to the cell;*

Comment: you forgot that you are reusing cells - that means everytime when you get an already used cell from the call to [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:contactCellIdentifier], you are duplicating the picture. in a reused cell, the picture may already be added as a subview - but anyways you are adding a new one. you should implement a check if the imageview is already there and if it is - dont create a new one. also take care with removing the images - if the imageview with tag 1290 is not available, the call to viewWithTag will return nil, and then you cannot call removeFrom Superview